# Warning: SecInfo Database Missing even though Feeds appear to be downloaded

Tags: openvas

I get the "SecInfo Database Missing" error:

> SCAP and/or CERT database missing on OMP server.

Even though I manually started a sync task and in the status it appears they are all complete (and have been for 20 minutes)

[image]

And in the console "about": `Feed Version: Thu Feb 7 13:52:00 2019`

I'm using the ISO from https://www.greenbone.net/en/install_use_gce/.  Brand new installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is apparently patience.

I just noticed that the "total" number on this chart is still growing:

[image]

This indicates that the feed is still downloading, which means that the status of "current" is misleading.